# how to stop execution after redirect_to is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i wrote an action which is again invoking another private method,
if a specific condition is met i want to redirect to some other page or else continue the execution.
but i was unable to do,
when i tried to use `redirect_to root_path` it says double render,
it is actually trying to execute the action statements which was actually called instead of rendering from the private method.

```
def actual_method_called
  data1 = params[:data1]
  method_2(data1)
  data2 = params[:data1]
  method_2(data2)
  render json: {status: 'ok' }
end

private

def method_2(data)
  if data.valid?
   puts 'continue the execution'
  else
   redirect_to root_path and return
  end
end
```

Comment: What version of Ruby on Rails are you using?

Comment: Rails 5.0.0.1 version
ruby 2.2.5p319

Comment: You could put `method_2` in `before_action` filter.

Comment: I misread your question and thought you were using a before_action.  There's a good answer now - you just have to return a value and use that to determine if you should render or not.  It might also make sense to refactor the code some way so that all rendering/redirecting is performed in a single method.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a value from the called method...

```
def method_2(data)
  if data.valid?
   puts 'continue the execution'
   return
  else
   redirect_to root_path 
    return :redirected 
  end
end
```

Wen you call it you store the returned value

```
def actual_method_called
  data1 = params[:data1]
  return_status ||= method_2(data1)
  data2 = params[:data1]
  return_status ||= method_2(data2)
  render json: {status: 'ok' } unless return_status == :redirected
end
```